# OSGi can't see class in .jar - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, jar, osgi

I'm trying to install .jar to CQ5 OSGi but whenever I try to use the code that's inside that package I get this error:

```
03.07.2013 08:47:05.650 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1372834022135] GET /content/TEST_hartmann/testdfs.html HTTP/1.1] maven.test.dfs [info.hartmann.dfs.impl.Handler] Error during instantiation of the implementation object (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/emc/documentum/fs/datamodel/core/context/Identity) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/emc/documentum/fs/datamodel/core/context/Identity
```

In my project, I use over 30 external (jar) libs that are in the root of that jar file and 3 my own classes which are in info/hartmann/dfs/impl and info/hartmann/dfs/api. Here is my MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Built-By: 302104
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_17
Bnd-LastModified: 1372834487861
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: DFS test
Bundle-SymbolicName: maven.test.dfs
Bundle-Version: 0.0.12.SNAPSHOT
Bundle-ClassPath: .
Embed-Dependency: *;scope=compile|runtime
Embed-Transitive: true
Export-Package: info.hartmann.dfs.api,
 com.emc.documentum.fs.aspects;uses:="org.aspectj.lang",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.admin,
 com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.admin.usermanagement;uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.properties,com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.admin",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.ci;uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,com.documentum.ci",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.collaboration;uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,
 com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.acl,
 com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.bpm;uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.bpm.taskmanagement;uses:="org.example.ws_ht",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.content;uses:="javax.xml.bind",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.context;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.profiles,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.properties,
   javax.xml.bind,
   javax.servlet.http",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.lifecycle;uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.profiles,
 com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.properties,
 com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.query,
 com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.schema,
 com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.vdm;uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.impl,
 com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.impl.soap,
 com.emc.documentum.fs.jaxws.compat,
 com.emc.documentum.fs.registry,
 com.emc.documentum.fs.registry.jaxr.impl;uses:="javax.xml.registry.infomodel,com.emc.documentum.fs.registry,javax.xml.registry",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt;uses:="javax.xml.bind",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.annotations,
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.profiles,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.properties,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.context",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.impl;
  uses:="com.documentum.fc.client,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.content,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.properties,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.profiles,
   com.documentum.ucf.server.transport,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.services,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.context,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.servicemodel,
   javax.xml.ws,
   javax.servlet.http,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.impl.compat;uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.impl",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.impl.reflection,
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.handlers;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.impl,
   javax.xml.ws.handler,
   javax.xml.ws.handler.soap,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.impl.soap,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.impl,
   com.documentum.operations.contentpackage,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.content,
   javax.xml.ws.handler,
   javax.servlet,
   javax.xml.ws,
   javax.servlet.http",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.configuration,
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.content;uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.content,com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.handler;uses:="javax.xml.ws.handler,javax.xml.ws.handler.soap",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.notification;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.content,
   com.documentum.ucf.common.notification,
   com.documentum.operations,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.pipe;
  uses:="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe,
   com.sun.xml.ws.api.message,
   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper,
   com.sun.xml.ws.api,
   javax.xml.bind,
   com.sun.xml.ws.util.pipe",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.richtext;uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,com.documentum.fc.common,com.documentum.services.richtext",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.servicemodel;
  uses:="javax.jws.soap,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt,
   javax.jws,
   javax.xml.bind",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.tx;uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.ucf;
  uses:="com.documentum.operations.contentpackage,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.content,
   com.documentum.operations,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.ucf.client;
  uses:="com.documentum.operations.contentpackage,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.content,
   com.documentum.operations,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.ucf",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.ucf.server;
  uses:="com.documentum.operations.contentpackage,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.content,
   com.documentum.operations,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.ucf,
   com.documentum.ucf.server.contentpackage",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.walker;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.content,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl,
   com.documentum.ucf.server.transport,
   com.documentum.fc.common,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.content",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.services;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.content,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.context,
   javax.xml.bind,
   javax.xml.ws,
   javax.xml.namespace",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.services.impl;uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.content,com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.context,javax.servlet.http",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.ucf;uses:="javax.servlet.http",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.admin;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.admin,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.admin.usermanagement,
   javax.xml.bind,
   javax.xml.ws,
   javax.xml.namespace",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.admin.client;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.admin,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.admin.usermanagement,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.servicemodel,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.bpm;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.bpm,
   javax.xml.bind,
   javax.xml.ws,
   javax.xml.namespace",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.bpm.client;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.bpm,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.servicemodel,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.ci;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt,
   javax.xml.bind,
   javax.xml.ws,
   javax.xml.namespace",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.ci.client;uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.servicemodel,com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.collaboration;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt,
   javax.xml.bind,
   javax.xml.ws,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.collaboration,
   javax.xml.namespace",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.collaboration.client;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.servicemodel,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.collaboration",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.properties,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.query,
   javax.xml.bind,
   javax.xml.ws,
   javax.xml.namespace,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.schema",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.acl;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.acl,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt,
   javax.xml.bind,
   javax.xml.ws,
   javax.xml.namespace",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.acl.client;uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.acl,com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.servicemodel,com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.client;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.properties,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.query,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.servicemodel,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.schema,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.lifecycle;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt,
   javax.xml.bind,
   javax.xml.ws,
   javax.xml.namespace",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.lifecycle.client;uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.servicemodel,com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.vdm;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt,
   javax.xml.bind,
   javax.xml.ws,
   javax.xml.namespace",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.vdm.client;uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.servicemodel,com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.impl.adapters;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.profiles,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.content,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.properties,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.impl.utils;uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.search;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.query,
   javax.xml.bind,
   javax.xml.ws,
   javax.xml.namespace",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.services.search.client;
  uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.query,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.servicemodel,
   com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.tracing;uses:="com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl,com.emc.documentum.fs.tracing.core",
 com.emc.documentum.fs.tracing.core
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/info.hartmann.dfs.impl.Handler.xml
Tool: Bnd-2.1.0.20130426-122213
```

I use Apache Maven to create the jar package, so here is my POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>maven.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-dfs</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.12-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>DFS test</name>

  <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>scr</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <archive>  
                  <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                </archive> 
              </configuration>
            </plugin>  
            <plugin>   
              <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                    <Export-Package>${project.exports}</Export-Package>  
                </instructions>
              </configuration>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                  <phase>process-classes</phase>
                  <goals>    
                    <goal>manifest</goal>
                  </goals>   
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.4</version>
               <configuration>
                  <descriptorRefs>
                     <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                  </descriptorRefs>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>emc-activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/activation.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>emc-aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/aspectjrt.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>emc-collaboration</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/collaboration.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>emc-commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/commons-io-1.2.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>emc-commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/commons-lang-2.4.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>emc-admin-services-remote</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/emc-admin-services-remote.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>emc-bpm-services-remote</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/emc-bpm-services-remote.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>emc-ci-services-remote</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/emc-ci-services-remote.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>emc-dfs-rt-remote</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/emc-dfs-rt-remote.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>emc-dfs-services-remote</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/emc-dfs-services-remote.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>emc-search-services-remote</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/emc-search-services-remote.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>FastInfoset</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/FastInfoset.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>http</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/http.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb1-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxb1-impl.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxb-api.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxb-impl.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxws-api.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxws-rt.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr173_api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jsr173_api.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jsr181-api.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jsr250-api.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/log4j.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/mimepull.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>resolver</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/resolver.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/saaj-api.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/saaj-impl.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/servlet.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>sjsxp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/sjsxp.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/stax-ex.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/streambuffer.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
        <artifactId>xerces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xerces-impl.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <!-- scr annotations - for generating component descriptors only -->
      <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>



  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <depl.user>user</depl.user>
    <depl.password>password</depl.password>
    <depl.host>localhost</depl.host>
    <depl.port>4502</depl.port>
  </properties>

</project>
```

I appreciate any help

**EDIT** this is how my jar file looks like

```
|   activation.jar
|   aspectjrt.jar
|   collaboration.jar
|   commons-io-1.2.jar
|   commons-lang-2.4.jar
|   dfc.properties
|   emc-admin-services-remote.jar
|   emc-bpm-services-remote.jar
|   emc-ci-services-remote.jar
|   emc-collaboration-services-remote.jar
|   emc-dfs-rt-remote.jar
|   emc-dfs-services-remote.jar
|   emc-search-services-remote.jar
|   FastInfoset.jar
|   http.jar
|   jaxb-api.jar
|   jaxb-impl.jar
|   jaxb1-impl.jar
|   jaxws-api.jar
|   jaxws-rt.jar
|   jsr173_api.jar
|   jsr181-api.jar
|   jsr250-api.jar
|   log4j.jar
|   mimepull.jar
|   resolver.jar
|   saaj-api.jar
|   saaj-impl.jar
|   servlet.jar
|   sjsxp.jar
|   stax-ex.jar
|   streambuffer.jar
|   xerces-impl.jar
|   
+---info
|   \---hartmann
|       \---dfs
|           +---api
|           |       HandlerApi.class
|           |       
|           \---impl
|                   Activator.class
|                   Handler.class
|                   
+---META-INF
|   |   MANIFEST.MF
|   |   
|   \---maven
|       \---maven.test
|           \---test-dfs
|                   pom.properties
|                   pom.xml
|                   
\---OSGI-INF
        info.hartmann.dfs.impl.Handler.xml
```

Comment: Is your jar file included in your build path?

Comment: @JREN what do you mean by "my jar file"? The jar that I create or jar with that missing class?

Comment: do you actually have the library jars within your jar or just located in the same place? if within your jar, that AFAIK won't work with standard classloader. if located in the same place, your bundle-classpath is wrong. Don't know about CQ5, but what you generally do in an OSGi env is to install the libraries as OSGi bundles and use Import-Package to use them.

Comment: The jar file that is supposed to hold this class. NoClassDefFoundException is only thrown when you try to access a class that doesn't exist at runtime. So I'm assuming that you have the jar in your project, but not in your build path

Comment: @eis I have it all together in one jar file.

Comment: @Jakolcz so, why? why don't you install the libraries as osgi bundles and use import-package?

Comment: @eis because these jars are not OSGi bundler and I'll have to OSGify them(won't I?). And also I thought it'll work that way I do it(I'm newbie in both OSGi and Maven).

Comment: yes, you need to either osgify them or download osgified versions, if they're not already. That's how it is supposed to happen in the OSGi world.

Comment: @eis I've added tree structure of my jar file to original post. OSGify all those jars is sth I'd like to do as one of the last options

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about CQ5 in specific, but in an OSGi container you should install the libraries as separate OSGi bundles and use Import-Package to get them in your classpath.

If they're not osgi-enabled, you need to either find OSGified versions, use bnd tool to get them osgified or package them with a correct handmade OSGi manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest, the package info.hartmann.dfs.impl is not listed, bnd (unless it is explicitly removed) lists these packages as Private-Package. I also do not see in the POM how you include your private package since you only use project.exports.

Now the error message is confusing in that case ... It shows that the Handler class exists but has no visibility to the documentum API. Not sure what is going on ...

Comment: My guess is that info.hartmann.dfs.impl is something contained in the same jar, which is probably found even without the private-package, with bundle-classpath. Documentum API is something in the other jar, so a regular classloader would not be able to find it since it is not packaged correctly.